# How to convert form-data(key, value) to raw json format in postman?

Tags: javascript, api, rest, testing, postman

I have a file with abcd.json extension which is inserted in form-data body with the header Content-Type:multipart/form-data and Accept:application/json. I want to convert this abcd.json file to raw json so that it can be posted in the raw body.
I tried using Content-Type:application/octet-stream but it is not working. I tried using the body as it is.
This is the data inside abcd.json file

```
{
   "name":"1",
   "description":"1",
   "height":1000,
   "width":1800,
   "zoom":"actual",
   "widgets":{
      "12345678-b6ab":{
         "id":"12345678-b6ab",
         "width":1760,
         "height":430,
         "x":19,
         "y":550,
         "minHeight":100,
         "minWidth":100,
         "zIndex":5,
         "content":{
            "widgetType":"historic",
            "params":{
               "data":[
                  0,
                  1
               ],
               "numberOfDecimals":"2",
               "selectedTimeRange":4,
               "aggregations":[
                  "none"
               ],
               "valueTypes":[
                  "none"
               ]
            }
         }
      },
      "abcdefgh-d5d9":{
         "id":"abcdefgh-d5d9",
         "width":1240,
         "height":250,
         "x":19,
         "y":9,
         "minHeight":20,
         "minWidth":20,
         "zIndex":6,
         "content":{
            "widgetType":"linechart",
            "params":{
               "data":1,
               "numberOfDecimals":2,
               "valueType":"value",
               "values":[
                  
               ],
               "timestamps":[
                  
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your type should be `application/json` when making the request

Comment: @DebarghaRoy Tried `Content-Type:application/json` that also it is throwing 400 error.

Comment: ` I want to convert this abcd.json file to raw json so that it can be posted in the raw body.` I don't understand what you want to say by this. A JSON is JSON irrespective of it's origin.   Can you share the API details that you're trying to hit?